# URL rewriting in nginX

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, nginx, seo

We currently run Apache and use .htaccess to rewrite URLs in several scripts including WordPress and OpenCart.

For performance reasons, we would like to move to a nginX+Varnish stack. How can we handle URL rewriting in nginX, and can we automate it, just the way WordPress and OpenCart write (into) .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

```
location ^~ /location {
  # some code else rewrite
  rewrite ^/your_rules # Or
  try_files $uri @rewrite_loc;
}

location @rewrite_loc {
  # some code
  # I guess you are not talking about proxy_pass
}
```

yes you can use `Nginx` just how you use with `Apache` and `.htaccess`, just need to define good rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks @jhilke-dai 1) Where do I put the above code, 2) Is there a way to automate this? I mean WordPress and OpenCart automatically generate .htaccess. Can I get them to automatically generate nginx config or wherever the above codes needs adding.

Comment: you can put the rewrite rule under `location block` which is inside the `server block`. It depends on what you want to Automate, I don't know what you are taking about Wordpress or Opencart automagically generates `.htaccess`  but there is no Automagical generation of `Nginx` config. You should define the possible outcome beforehand. You can check those `.htaccess` and define `Nginx` config according to it. Does the `.htaccess` keeps changing ? I hope not